# Word preceded by two spaces

Tags: regex

I need to find a word that is preceded by two spaces.

```
not found
  goto home
```

I need goto to be the matched word in that example.
I'm very, very new to regex and still learning so any explanation in your answer would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what language or text editor you're using, but this works:

```
^  (\w+)
```

Just capture group 1 ($1) and you're good to go!

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-mcI7xGbwBuieZMR)

Alternatively, you could use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=  )(\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/G3S7igvUafpiwDT-)

(Interestingly, at least on Debuggex, using Python flavor, combining the lookbehind with `^` fails.)

Comment: Just a quick question. What is the "^" doing?

Comment: @bmandesign, `^` matches at the beginning of the line or string.

Comment: Right. So `[SPACE][SPACE]goto` is matched, but `[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]goto` is not.

Comment: How could I make it so "  goto" or "  open" would match but other words like "  random" wouldn't? Sorry about the beginner questions. Only started regex yesterday.

Comment: @bmandesign, `^  (goto|open)\b`. Without `\b` it also matches `  opening`.

Comment: @falsetru I tried and without `\b` works fine for me. It does't match `opening`

Answer (score 1):

Use following regular expression:

```
^  (\w+)
```

You may need additional flag in some regular expression engine.

For example, in Javascript, you need `m` flag:

```
var s = "not found\n  goto home";
s.match(/^  (\w+)/m)[1] // => "goto"
```